# How does AWS Athena max function deals with Null values

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table in AWS Athena with a column that contains NULL values.

I want to calculate the max value for this column.

How would Athena calculate max value for a column that contains both Nulls and non-Nulls?

For the following example:

[image]

What would be the output for the following query:

```
select max(uploaded_mb) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Presto [`max()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max) function returns the maximum value of all input values. Nulls won't affect that.

Here's an example query that shows that NULLs are ignored:

```
WITH
  t1 AS (SELECT 1 AS a),
  t2 AS (SELECT NULL AS a),
  tf AS (
    SELECT * FROM t1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM t2
  )
SELECT max(a)
FROM tf
```

Did you get an error or see unexpected behaviour when using `max()`?

Comment: "Did you get an error or see unexpected behaviour when using max()?"

   nope, just didn't know how to test max function behaviour without creating a temporary table.

   thanks for the example of how to test aggregate functions